# Is there a way to run a python shell in the background (of latex)?

Tags: python, linux, bash, latex

I need to execute Python code from Latex files (for including experiment data).

The CTAN package `python` kind of serves this purpose, but for some reason is not able to output into figure captions.

I hacked together a `write18` based solution that works fine, but I got the idea that it would be better to have a python shell "session" running in the background. That way I could just load my data once in the beginning.

In theory this should be possible using Linux fifos:

```
# create fifos
mkfifo /tmp/infifo
mkfifo /tmp/outfifo

# start python process
python < /tmp/infifo > /tmp/outfifo & 

# listen for results
cat /tmp/outfifo &

# write something 
echo "print('hello world')" > /tmp/infifo
-> hello world
```

But after this short interaction the python and the output cat process terminate. Using `cat` instead of `echo` to send data to the process makes the processes linger, but the answers seem to be buffered and get send only after the input cat process is terminated.

Comment: Did you try `pythontex`? (I don't know of it works in captions)

Comment: I saw it, but I haven't looked into it too much because it's a pre-processor. Might be worth another shot thou.

Comment: I looked into it again ... and while it is a pre-processor it integrates nicely with latexmk (and my setup here). So thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Oh, that is great to hear! Maybe you could write a short answer for future users with the same problem?

Comment: @samcarter It's really finicky to get it to do what I want ... not sure if I can recommend it yet.